# Side effects when not using the -u option of aspnet_compiler.exe

Tags: asp.net, compiler-construction

Following is the MSDN instruction, but not sure what it means:

**-u**

> Specifies that Aspnet_compiler.exe should create a precompiled
>   application that allows subsequent updates of contents such as .aspx
>   pages. If this option is omitted, the resulting application contains
>   only compiled files and cannot be updated on the deployment server.
>   You can update the application only by changing the source markup
>   files and recompiling. The targetDir parameter must be included.

Can anyone explain it for me.

Answer (score 2):

If you specify `-u` the markup of your pages and controls (aspx/ascx) will be left intact and will be compiled just-in-time (e.g. when first accessed). This allows you to edit the markup directly on the deployment server (without having to rebuild/publish the solution).

If you don't specify `-u`, then the markup is compiled and the pages/controls are replaced with empty place-holder files. If you need to make a change to the markup, you have to do it on your development server, then rebuild/publish the solution.

[This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229863%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) explains all the options of aspnet_compiler.exe.

---

BTW: this part of the documentation may be important for deciding whether to use `-u` or not:

> When you use [the `-u` option], code blocks in .aspx files (that is, code
>   located in script elements or between <% and %> tags) are not
>   compiled. Therefore, **if there are compile errors** in those code blocks,
>   **you will see the error only at run time**, because the .aspx file is
>   fully compiled only then. It is generally unsafe to use this option
>   for a site that relies on code blocks in .aspx files.